# SASS + Compass "doesn't support keyword arguments"

Tags: sass, gulp, compass-sass, compass

I'm running gulp with sass and compass, and I'm encountering the following error:

```
[02:12:28] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Site/gulpfile.js
[02:12:28] Starting 'sass'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    scss/helpers/_vars.scss
Error: Function sprite-map doesn't support keyword arguments
        on line 6 of scss/helpers/_vars.scss
>> $sprite2x: sprite-map("../../images/icons-2x/*.png", $spacing: 5px, $repeat:
   -----------^
```

In my vars sass helper, for that particular line, I'm using:

```
$sprite2x: sprite-map("../../images/icons-2x/*.png", $spacing: 5px, $repeat: no-repeat);
```

Has someone come across this before and is there any reason why it's not supporting those arguments?
I've checked on the [Compass Helper](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-map) section for sprite maps and I don't see anything wrong?

> Default values for all sprites can be specified by passing values for
>   $position, $spacing, and $repeat.

Comment: If you run Compass directly (outside of gulp), do you get the same error?  The only error I can get Compass to generate is `No files were found in the load path matching "../../images/icons-2x/*.png". Your current load paths are: ...`.  Adjusting the path to point to an actual directory containing images does not produce any further errors.